# swift 3 webView background color

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I need a help with `webView` in swift 3.

I'm making a reader that read books in the html format - the problem is with the `webView` background colour.

I'm setting `webView` to break content on pages, like this:

```
    webView.paginationBreakingMode = .page
```

I'm setting the background in CSS, like this:

`* {background-color: red;}`

But I'm still getting a white background. This is not `webView` background, this is something else.

[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YARR.png)

Comment: Do you have the webview in a storyboard? If so, select it and under the attributes inspector change the background color.

Comment: yes , I do this , no effect

Answer (score 7):

It can be done by setting in IB the webview's opaque property to NO.
And set the background of the underneath view to desired colour.

Comment: It's work , if we don't use paginationBreakingMode. I need this to work in horizontal mode

Comment: `self.webView.isOpaque = false;`
`self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Try to set backgroundColor to UIColor.clear to check layer?